# Why do paramiko produces false results while using with multi-threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, paramiko

I am trying SSH to hosts (number in hundreds) using paramiko with multithreading.

Here is my code with multithreading,

```
import paramiko
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# Initialising paramiko SSH Client
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Fetching hosts
file = open("hosts.txt")
content = file.readlines()
hosts = [host.strip() for host in content]

def ssh(host):
    try:
        print("Connecting to", host)
        client.connect(host,
                       username="SOMEUSER",
                       password="SOMEPASS",
                       timeout=1,
                       banner_timeout=1,
                       auth_timeout=1)
        print("Connected to", host)
        # Need to check something here...
        client.close()
        print(f"Connection to {host} closed.")
        return True
    except:
        print("FAILED to connect", host)
        return False

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(ssh, hosts))

for i, host in enumerate(hosts):
    print(host, "=>", results[i])
```

Q1: **I am getting false results compared to the code without any multithreading. What is wrong with my multithreading here and how can I make this work?**

Q2: **Somehow the below exception is being raised (multiple times) and I have no idea how this exception is not getting caught?**

```
Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tesit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2211, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "/home/tesit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 380, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/home/tesit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 619, in _read_timeout
    raise EOFError()
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tesit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2039, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "/home/tesit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2216, in _check_banner
    "Error reading SSH protocol banner" + str(e)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

Comment: Increase your timeout in the first place. Maybe a heavy load like this prevents the data to arrive in time. Also why would you like to create hundreds of SSH connections in seconds?

Comment: I need to check if a particular file is present in hosts periodically. I've tried with a timeout of 4 seconds also and it didn't help! Also, those exceptions left me scratching my head

Comment: What about creating clients for each connection?

Comment: @nagyl, It really worked out! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome !:)

Answer (score 2):

Moving the initialization of Paramiko SSH Client inside the function definition done the trick for me! Now code works correctly as compared to the one without multithreading.

Here is my code after fixing the problem

```
import paramiko
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

file = open("hosts.txt")
content = file.readlines()
hosts = [host.strip() for host in content]

def ssh(host):
    try:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        print("Connecting to", host)
        client.connect(host,
                       username="SOMEUSER",
                       password="SOMEPASS",
                       timeout=1,
                       banner_timeout=1,
                       auth_timeout=1)
        print("Connected to", host)
        # Need to check something here...
        client.close()
        print(f"Connection to {host} closed.")
        return True
    except:
        print("FAILED to connect", host)
        return False

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    output = list(executor.map(ssh, hosts))

for i, host in enumerate(hosts):
    print(host, "=>", output[i])
```

Even though now the code works well as I intended, the below **exception is not getting caught!**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tesit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2211, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "/home/tesit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 380, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/home/tesit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 607, in _read_timeout
    x = self.__socket.recv(128)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tesit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2039, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "/home/tesit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2216, in _check_banner
    "Error reading SSH protocol banner" + str(e)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: also want to catch this